# Django, Celery - How can I run a task for every 45 days at a particular time

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I need to run a task every 45 days at a particular time using Celery. I tried using "time delta" of python DateTime library as follows but I can't specify a particular time. Can anyone help me on this, please?

```
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
'add-every-45-days': {
    'task': 'tasks.add',
    'schedule': timedelta(days=45),
},
```

}

Comment: As I know, cron allows to use specific time or interval (not both at the same time).